# php: try catch / error freezes server script

Tags: php, try-catch, freeze

I am running a cronjob script which completely freezes within a try / catch statement (which is inside a while loop).
The catch phrase is working as it's logging the error (which i put there) but then it freezes completely without any output.
after that i only put `echo "error";` inside the catch pharse but it does not output and freezes again.
when adding `die;` it prompts and the script stops as expected - but i want to catch the error and continue the script.

```
while($rs = $res->fetch_assoc())
{

    try
    {
        $rc = new c_movie();
        $result = $rc->search();

    } catch(Throwable $t)
    {
        echo "ERROR!!!!";  // freezing here, does not echo
    }

}
```

any idea what could be causing the script to freeze?
thanks

Comment: Please share the relevant code - it's difficult to debug descriptions.

Comment: Either you're not sharing enough of your code or it doesn't make any sense. You're not using any data out of row `$rs`. Also, could it just be that `$res->fetch_assoc()` has only one result?

Comment: What does `search` do? Does it have an internal loop of its own? It's difficult to imagine `$rs = $res->fetch_assoc()` producing an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, where do you expect to see the output? If it's an automated cron job, you'd have to capture it inside a file. Or are you manually running the script in a browser or CLI to test it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out by myself .. my code was using get_headers() which caused the freeze when trying to load a URL which had 404. Seems like the server is somekind of caching it and freezes and won't trigger the exception. Very Strange ..